Firebase Functions NOT_FOUND for europe regions
I have tried to create an function in europe-central2 region.
Unfortunately, I got this error if the function is not in the default region when calling from the Kotlin sdk:
return Firebase.functions.httpsCallable("returnDistricts").invoke().data<String>()

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.app.afterfood.android, PID: 6689
   com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: NOT_FOUND at com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctions$2.onResponse(FirebaseFunctions.java:388)

It works perfect if it is in default region: us-central1.
Any idea if it is possible to call a function that is not in the default region?

This is covered in the documentation:

Note: To call a function running in any location other than the default us-central1, you must set the appropriate value at initialization. For example, on Android you would initialize with getInstance(FirebaseApp app, String region).

This means you will need to need to get a FirebaseFunctions instance using getInstance, passing the region to use for that FirebaseApp instance in the second paramter.
Firebase.functions
    .getInstance(/* your region params */)
    .httpsCallable(...)


You are right. Thank you. Should I put the region the same as the Firestore DB region?

You should benchmark your options and the conditions under which those options will be used, and make a determination from there.  I can't tell you what's best for your use case.  But it's common sense to co-locate cloud products in the same region to make it faster for them to communicate between each other directly.  Whether or not that's good for all of the end users of your app could be a different matter.
